# Replacing missing numbers based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have the following problem: I have a dataset with three variables. let's call them a, b and c.

I have to combine them to an additive index. But if one of the three is missing, I have to replace it with a certain value (0.5). If two or three are missing, it stays NA.

ds is the name of the dataset

```
for(i in ds$a) {
  if is.na(i) && !is.na(ds$b) && !is.na(ds$c)  {
    ds$a <- 0.5
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset (use `dput(ds)`) and your desired outcome?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

Would you please clarify the term "combine them to an additive index". Does it mean you want to `rowsum` three existing columns? And also not clear why you are replacing values to the existing variable `a` when the conditions are met?

I have way around of your problem that checks your NA conditions(and replaces to a new column)

```
 (ds <- data.frame(a= c(1,NA,2),
                  b= c(10,20,30), 
                  c= c(100,200,300)))
   a  b   c
1  1 10 100
2 NA 20 200
3  2 30 300
 
 (flag <-  sapply(ds, anyNA))  ## check whether any NA's columns-wise
    a     b     c 
 TRUE FALSE FALSE 
 
 if(sum(flag)==1){
   ds$d <- 0.5 
 }else if(sum(flag) %in% 2:3){
   ds$d <- NA
 }
 ds
   a  b   c   d
1  1 10 100 0.5
2 NA 20 200 0.5
3  2 30 300 0.5
```